# Anyone used Sencha Touch and EE for ecommerce?

Tags: cartthrob

I'm looking to build a new ipad and iPhone website for a client. I'm looking at Sencha Touch as the solution with Carththrob running the ecommerce side of things.

As anyone had any experience with this set up?

Looking at the Sencha docs, I'm thinking of using XTemplates quite heavily to accommodate CTs forms etc.

Any heads up would be fantastic!

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an interesting mix. I don't know your exact use case but personally I'm not sure I'd look to go with that combination. Sencha Touch is great as a feature-reach mobile framework which is aimed at providing a native app look and feel. As you mentioned you're building a `website` for a client. The [website vs web app debate](http://theappslab.com/2010/11/12/website-vs-web-app/) is endless but generally if you're building some to look native to the mobile device then I'd say it's an app. Web apps generally tend to be front-end heavy primarily using HTML5 and JS to provide the application logic. As a result it's common that they only ever need a thin client on the server - just an simple [RESTful interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) to connect to for [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD) operations. In which case I'd tend to use something like [Deployd](http://www.deployd.com/) which is built for the purpose and very easy to get started with or just build my own in pure code with a framework.

If it needed ecommerce and Cartthrob, baskets, and order forms etc were being considered then I wouldn't go for a native look and feel app. That would be more a `website` which I'd look to build [responsively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design). Then I'd look to use EE and CT but I then wouldn't consider using Sencha Touch. It's too complete a framework and I wouldn't want the `native` look and feel.

You could always try and turn EE into a RESTful interface of sorts (although not true RESTful) but it almost seems like overkill if it's for a mobile `app`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Some very good points raised. I use the 'wonderful' Bootstrap a bit, bit am not keen on the sites produced for tablets and phones etc. There is a great addon for REST/SOAP CRUD called Entry API - worth looking at if you have seen it (Its on Dev:otee). I see your logic with the heaviness of Sencha - Some great features that I can't seem to find anywhere else. I really like the iPad split screen - JQuery mobile has some attempts at this, but nothing brilliant. Thanks again for the feedback - most useful.

Comment: I've seen Entry API before but like I said, I would consider it overkill to buy a large and powerful commercial bit of software just to use it as a lightweight API. Heavy on both the front and back isn't a good combination. Why don't you just build a responsive website where you can split screen or adapt it however much you like fitting in with your own design? If there's a lot of JS then I'd use require.js (for modular control) and backbone.js (for structure) to organise.